# Build Eclipse Feature Project using ANT

Tags: ant, build, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Plugin development and hence facing this issue.

I have 2 plugin projects and both the projects are part of a feature project. I want to set up an ANT build which could build the feature project and publish it to an URL or File system.

Here is the scenario:
Plugin Project A isDependentOn -> Plugin Project B.

For both these project, I wrote build files which builds them properly.

Now I created a Feature project and included both these plugins into it. However I am not able to correctly write the ANT build file or may be I am not sure of the complete process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Its better use Maven with Tycho to build eclipse features and plugins in headless mode.

Refer the link [Eclipse Tycho](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) and [Using Tycho](http://www.ancitconsulting.com/tiki-index.php?page=tutorials)

Comment: Yes, but the requirements are such, that Maven plugins are not possible. Hence, the issue. Though I tried creating a Feature project to include my plugins in the feature project.

However, now the problem where I am stuck is automatically build the UpdateSite project using ANT.

Any pointers would be really helpful.